# Nest : getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized while fetching devices using curl

Tags: rest, curl, firebase, nest-api, firebase-authentication

I'm getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized if I want to fetch Nest devices using

```
curl -v -L https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/?auth=<AUTHCODE>
```

I don't have any device in my Nest account. I think I should get HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

I tried to fetch thermostats with this command

```
curl -v -L https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats?auth=<AUTHCODE>
```

then it replies back with HTTP/1.1 200 OK with same AUTHCODE which I think is correct. Again mentioning that I don't have any device in my account.

So there is difference in the response that I'm getting. My question is that why am I getting 401 Unauthorized instead of 404 not found or 200 ok for the first curl command?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Frank I've edited the question.

Comment: What are the permissions on your nest client?

Comment: @urman I have following permissions on my nest client : Away read/write, Smoke+CO alarm read, Thermostat read/write.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I used the URL you gave:

```
    https://developer-api.nest.com/devices?auth=<AUTHCODE>
```

but also included into the headers:

```
    Authorization: Bearer <AUTHCODE>
    Content-Type: application/json
```

then it seemed to work!

Comment: Actually, now that I have it working correctly, I see that the URL doesn't need the "?auth=<AUTHCODE>" and the first header should be "Authorization:  Bearer <AUTHCODE>"; i.e., you actually put the word "Bearer " in front of your authcode as the value of the header.  Sorry for the confusion.  (Also, I note that the Nest API server is **really bad** at giving good error messages.  If a single character of your URL is wrong, you'll be told that your body text is wrong instead of pointing to the URL as the problem.