# Nest - Getting incorrect response with zero devices in nest account

Tags: rest, firebase, nest-api, firebase-authentication

I have zero devices in my Nest account. When I want to fetch devices using

```
curl -v -L https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/?auth=<AUTHCODE>
```

I get 401 Unauthorized as response. Why I'm getting this response?

Nest-API specifies that 401 Unauthorized is returned when the user has deleted the Works with Nest connection from the Nest app, and subsequently revoked their authorization code.

But when I try to fetch thermostat data with the same AUTHCODE using this command

```
curl -v -L https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats?auth=<AUTHCODE>
```

I'm getting proper responses as per the documentation by Nest.

Comment: Same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676248/nest-getting-http-1-1-401-unauthorized-while-fetching-devices-using-curl

Comment: What permissions does your nest client have?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : Yes

Comment: @urman :  I have following permissions on my nest client : Away read/write, Smoke+CO alarm read, Thermostat read/write